# create windows(.exe) file using adobe flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've create an app using flash cc for android. It works great but now my goal is to publish it in windows. I know I can use air for windows. I've tried it and it works. But the problem with that is, you can see all the swf files on installed folder. That makes my files vulnerable for theft. So I want to know if there's any methods or converter to convert my whole air application in exe so that it doesn't expose all the included swf files. I think game like machinarium was created using flash. But when I got the setup file it include exe files and non of flash files or any other files were exposed. Is it possible to achieve with flash as3? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the software you use to create EXE files that play SWFs?

Comment: I'm not using any software. I'm just curious if such can be achieved using adobe flash.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Adobe Flash you can go to your publish settings and a small menu will pop up and there will be tabs at the top. Go to the tab that has a list of the various file formats you can export to and .exe will be one of them. Check the box and then set the file location, then hit 'Publish' and you should have an .exe file.

Comment: thank u for reply. I looked at publish setting but I did not find any such tab. My publish setting got profile, player, script etc. On the left it has publish and other formats. Did u mean win projector on other format?